# Why strings are declared or defined using character pointer

Tags: c, string, pointers, character

I dont know why we always declare like this

```
char* name="Srimanth"
```

instead of

```
char name[]={"Srimanth"}
```

I am new to this things. so please be more specific while you are giving me an answer..

thank you.

Comment: `char* name="";` is bad practice, always declare such pointers as `const char*`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

String literal is a special, simple, form of writing an array aggregate: you can write `"hello"` instead of `{'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0'}` (note the terminating zero, which is added automatically).

Note that an array declaration is not only possible, but is sometimes desirable:

```
char str[] = "hello";
str[0] = 'H'; // OK
```

lets you modify the string, as opposed to

```
char *str = "hello";
str[0] = 'H'; // Undefined behavior
```

which does not allow modifications.

Comment: @Noob.Alone.Programmer You are welcome! If you are no longer actively looking for an improved answer, consider accepting this one by clicking the grey check mark next to it. This would earn you a new badge on stack overflow, and indicate to others that you have an answer.

Comment: Additional point, to the answer of dasblinkenlight. It is a good practice to use `const char *` in place of `char *`. That will alert  in compilation time if the string literal is modified.